# Extended Splash Screen - ProgressRing disappers on mobile

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have made an ExtendedSplashScreen by following the Microsoft docs. I have a logo and a `ProressRing` in the splash screen. It works well on desktop (Logo is in the center and `ProgressRing` is below it). But on my mobile, the `ProgressRing` disappears ( probably goes out of view ) but the logo is in the center. 
Here's my XAML:

```
<Grid Background="#FFFFFF">
        <Canvas>
            <Image x:Name="extendedSplashImage" Source="/Assets/GeneraredSplash/SplashScreen.scale-100.png"/>
            <ProgressRing Name="splashProgressRing" IsActive="True" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

Code:

```
namespace Project.Views
{
    partial class ExtendedSplash : Page
    {        
        internal Rect splashImageRect; // Rect to store splash screen image coordinates.
        private SplashScreen splash; // Variable to hold the splash screen object.
        internal bool dismissed = false; // Variable to track splash screen dismissal status.
        internal Frame rootFrame;

        public ExtendedSplash(SplashScreen splashscreen, bool loadState)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Window.Current.SizeChanged += new WindowSizeChangedEventHandler(ExtendedSplash_OnResize);
            splash = splashscreen;
            if (splash != null)
            {
                // Register an event handler to be executed when the splash screen has been dismissed.
                splash.Dismissed += new TypedEventHandler<SplashScreen, Object>(DismissedEventHandler);
                // Retrieve the window coordinates of the splash screen image.
                splashImageRect = splash.ImageLocation;
                PositionImage();
                // Optional: Add a progress ring to your splash screen to show users that content is loading
                PositionRing();
            }
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context
            rootFrame = new Frame();
        }

        // Position the extended splash screen image in the same location as the system splash screen image.
        void PositionImage()
        {
            double ScaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;

            extendedSplashImage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, splashImageRect.Left);
            extendedSplashImage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, splashImageRect.Top);

            if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
            {
                extendedSplashImage.Height = splashImageRect.Height / ScaleFactor;
                extendedSplashImage.Width = splashImageRect.Width / ScaleFactor;
            }
            else
            {
                extendedSplashImage.Height = splashImageRect.Height;
                extendedSplashImage.Width = splashImageRect.Width;
            }
        }

        void PositionRing()
        {
            double ScaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;

            splashProgressRing.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, splashImageRect.X + (splashImageRect.Width * 0.5) - (splashProgressRing.Width * 0.5));
            splashProgressRing.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (splashImageRect.Y + splashImageRect.Height + splashImageRect.Height * 0.1));

            if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
            {
                splashProgressRing.Height = splashProgressRing.Height / ScaleFactor;
                splashProgressRing.Width = splashProgressRing.Width / ScaleFactor;
            }
        }

        //Other methods like DismissExtendedSplash(), DismissedEventHandler(), ExtendedSplash_OnResize(Object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e).....
    }
}
```

I am not very familiar with image scaling, RawPixels, ScaleFactor etc. .
I found the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958367/windows-uwp-extended-splash-screen-image-rendering-incorrectly-on-mobile)

Also if you guys know some good tutorial for splash screen or something similar (other than Microsoft docs) that can help then please post the link to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `ProgressRing` control inside the Grid. It should always be in the center of the page, not the center of any child.

Also `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` won't do anything within a Canvas. You need to use **Canvas.Left** and **Canvas.Top**.

Comment: I want the progress ring to be below my logo